# How do I get maximum offline storage from within a web site?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to develop a cross platform application, where the most obvious route would be a web site with JavaScript, but then I lose the cosy comforts I'm used to using in my C# desktop apps, like file system access etc.  How do I go about accessing *similar* services from within the browser?

E.g. I don't need to access anything I don't create, so actual file system access is just a luxury.  I can use whatever the browser offers for offline storage, but have no clue how to do this.

Comment: Why do you think you need to know this? With current HD sizes, most users have far more storage than any sensible application could need.

Comment: Yes, but I can't get at all that juicy HD space from the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Google Gears](http://code.google.com/intl/sv/apis/gears/api_database.html).

Answer (score 5):

Depending what you need to store you could possibly use a cookie.

For larger storage this is what the upcoming HTML5 client-side storage methods address, but we're not quite there yet.

Security concerns prevent browsers from getting real access to storing things client-side for the most part, though.

Answer (score 0):

For simple file manipulation, why not use a well established protocol like FTP?

It's accessible both from browsers and from code.

If you're encountering firewall/security/permissions concerns, you can always use HTTP.
It all depends on how you access your storage.